# Как для бота discord сделать команду для вывода постоянно разного числа?

Tags: python, discord, случайные-числа

Возможно ли для бота discord сделать команду для рандомного числа (по типу dice) с одним randint, но что бы выводилось постоянно разное число? Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Возможно. Строки кода есть в документации, а почему вы её не поняли, мы не знаем

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Делаем асинхронную команду и готово, всегда разное число.
Диапазон чисел делаем в скобках.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!', intents=intents)


@bot.command()
async def rand(ctx):
    random_number = random.randint(1, 999)
    await ctx.send(f'Случайное число: {random_number}')

bot.run('ваш токен')
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое, это помогло. Правда в строке "bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!', intents=intents)" не надо использовать "intents=intents". Да и вместо "intents.message_content = True" я использовал " intents = discord.Intents(messages=True, guilds=True)"

Comment: Я лишь как пример дал весь код бота, который можно проверить, суть в команде внутри, но в любом случае, рад, что смог помочь. 
Если мой ответ смог решить Вашу проблему, буду рад, если выберете его, как решение. 
Удачной разработки!

Answer (score 1):

Возможно. Реализовать это можно по-разному.
Если брать игральную кость для примера, то это случайные значения от 1 до 6:

```
import random

my_list = list(range(1, 7))  # создаем список из чисел
random.shuffle(my_list)  # перемешиваем элементы списка
for i in my_list:
    print(i)
```

Если нужно одно случайное число:

```
import random

my_list = list(range(1, 7))
random.shuffle(my_list)


def get_random_digit():
    global my_list
    if len(my_list) == 0:
        my_list = list(range(1, 7))
        random.shuffle(my_list)
    print(my_list.pop())


get_random_digit()
```

Comment: Добавьте наверное ещё пример с randint, и объясните что присвоенный переменной результат будет всегда один и тот же.

Comment: Теперь как мне сделать так, чтобы выводилось только 1 число из всех, а не сразу 6??

Comment: @kabezajka ```print(my_list.pop())``` при этом, это удалит из списка ```my_list``` этот элемент, и когда список опустеет, его нужно будет снова наполнить.

Comment: @kabezajka добавил вариант пополняемого списка и получения 1 случайного числа

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

a = random.randint(1, 9999)
x = []
if a in x:
    print("Такое число уже было")
else:
    x.append(a)
    print(x)
```

Так не подойдет? для random.randint можно перебор бесконечных чисел сделать

Ну если так не работает, попробуйте просто местами поменять, как бы это глупо не звучало:

```
x = []
a = random.randint(1, 9999)
if a not in  x:
    x.append(a)
    print(*x)
else:
    print("Такое число уже было")
print(x)
```

Comment: Только выводится список, а не число. Тогда print(*x) в конце

Comment: У меня выводится число, а потом бесконечно "такое уже было". Может, это проблема в самом дискорд пай? Или типа того, не знаю...

Comment: Да, точно. В конце просто print(*x) напишите и выведет число

Comment: Вроде все должно работать. На своем боте проверил.

Comment: Нижний принт мне для проверки нужен был. Его можно убрать